# A calculation/logic problem for an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose for a given $\epsilon$ I want to find a $\delta_\epsilon$ such that such that $|x-y| < \delta_\epsilon$ ($x \geq 1, y \geq 1)$ implies $|\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}| < \epsilon$ which implies that 
$$\left|\frac{(y-x)(y+x)}{x^2y^2}\right| < \epsilon \tag{1}$$

i.e $|x-y| < \frac{\epsilon x^2 y^2}{x+y}$. So, if we make sure that our $\delta_\epsilon < \frac{\epsilon x^2 y^2}{x+y}$  which requires $\delta_\epsilon \geq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ (using the fact that $\frac{x+y}{x^2y^2} \leq 2$). But this  is contradictory to the requirement which comes from equation (1) which says that 
$\delta_\epsilon \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. I am sure I am making calculation mistakes somewhere. Where ?

Comment: Recheck your first implication:$\delta < \epsilon \frac{x^2y^2}{x + y}$ and $
\frac{x + y}{x^2y^2} \leq 2$ implies $\delta < \epsilon \frac{x^2y^2}{x + y} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ which doesn't really get you anywhere.

Comment: @BaronVT: I said "requires" not implies. Still not able to find out my mistake

Comment: Well, it doesn't require it either. The statements $a < b$ and $b > c$ don't say *anything* about the relative size of $a$ and $c$. (for instance, this is true with $a = 1, b= 3, c=2$ as well as $a = 2, b = 3, c = 1$.)

Comment: I did not say that. I have to find a $b$ such that $a<b$ holds given that $a<c$. If I choose $b<c$ then my goal will be met. Here $a=\frac{x+y}{x^2y^2}, b=\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}, c=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Ok, so what do you mean when you say "So, if we make sure that our $\delta_\epsilon < \epsilon \frac{x^2 y^2}{x+y}$ which requires $\delta_\epsilon \geq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ (using the fact that $\frac{x^2 y^2}{x+y}\geq \frac{1}{2}$" (I switched the last inequality, but it's the same mathematically)

Comment: And when you say  "I have to find a b such that a<b holds given that a<c. If I choose b<c then my goal will be met." Try this with actual numbers: if $c = 5$ and $a = 4$ (so $a<c$), then choosing any $b<5$ alone will not ensure $4<b$ holds.

Answer (score 0):

You are also assuming that $x,y \ge 1$. This means that $$\left| \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{y^2} \right| = |x-y| \left| \frac{y+x}{x^2 y^2} \right| = |x-y| \left( \frac{1}{x^2 y} + \frac{1}{x y^2} \right) \le 2 |x-y|.$$

That is, $|x-y| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ implies $\left| \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{y^2} \right| < \epsilon$.